# Append char arrays to create string

Tags: java, string, split, arrays

How do i add all charAcro[] to create a string? example
charAcro[0] = a, charAcro[1] = b, charAcro[2] = c, which makes the string abc

```
 while(resultSet.next()){
                    String Name = rs.getString(1);
                    String Acro=Name;
                    String delimiterAcro = " ";
                    String[] temp =null;
                    char[] charAcro = null;
                    temp = Name.split(delimiterAcro);
                    for(int i = 0;i<temp.length;++i){
                    charAcro[i] = temp[i].charAt(0);
                    //SOME CODE HERE?
                    }

      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `String` constructor available that takes a `char` array,

```
char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(data);
```

While I'm at it, look into [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Whereas variables are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters.

For example in your code snippet you have,

```
String Name = rs.getString(1);
```

which is bad, if not wrong.

Moreover, you are likely to have a NullPointerException at line,

```
charAcro[i] = temp[i].charAt(0);
```

as you didn't initialise the array. Below is the code which should work for you.

```
String name = rs.getString(1);
String[] temp = name.split(" ");
char[] charAcro = new char[temp.length];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
    charAcro[i] = temp[i].charAt(0);
}
System.out.println(new String(charAcro));
```

Comment: I answered with a StringBuilder, but this is a much more elegant solution. Kudos.

Answer (score 4):

There's a constructor for String that accepts a char array, so just do:

```
String string = new String(charAcro);
```